# How enable FXP (server to server transfer) in Windows Server (IIS FTP)?

Tags: iis-6, ftp

I want use server to server FTP between Windows Server 2008 and 2003 using the built in IIS FTP.

How can I enable it?

Comment: if you know any better solution from IIS FTP service, please offer some free service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Server 2003 and 2008 come with IIS FTP 6.0. [Enable FXP in IIS6 - MS Article 247132](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb%3BEN-US%3B247132)

Comment: @uSlackr, that isn't a typo. FXP is the File eXchange Protocol extension to FTP.

Comment: My bad.  Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247132

This article doesn't cover server 2008, but I would guess things function similarly.

Comment: Server 2008 actually comes with IIS FTP 6.0, so those directions do cover it.

Comment: windows server 2008 run FTP 6, so this article cover that